# Why the plot of Octave 3.8 and 4.x looks so differently?

Tags: plot, octave

The plot of Octave 4.x is ugly, how can I make it the same as 3.8.2. For example, the grid on command in Octave 4.x will produce solid-line grids which overlapped on your plot which is totally unacceptable!

This is new style:
[image: Plot generated with Octave 4.x]

Comment: note that you can fully customise the appearance of the gridlines if you don't like the defaults! Personally I don't think the defaults are ugly, but I guess this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Octave has many graphics backends. For release 4.0 they changed the default one. From the release notes:

> Octave now uses OpenGL graphics with Qt widgets by default.  If OpenGL libraries are not available when Octave is built, gnuplot is used. You may choose to use the fltk or gnuplot toolkit for graphics by executing the command
>
> ```
> graphics_toolkit ("fltk")
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot")
> ```
>
> Adding such a command to your `~/.octaverc` file will set the default for each session.

[This documentation page](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Graphics-Toolkits.html) will help you to get started exploring these backends. For example:

```
graphics_toolkit
```

will show the default backend name, and

```
graphics_toolkit(name)
```

will set the default to `name`. You can list available backends with:

```
available_graphics_toolkits
```

Comment: Actually I'm using jupyter with octave, with `available_graphics_toolkits` I found only `ans =
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
}`. And I did install libfltk, but I cannot found it. In fact, when I was in octave 3.8 the toolkit was also gnuplot. I noticed there was a saying from Octave 4.0 which said it supports OpenGL rendering now. I'm not sure if this is the major reason why the plot system had changed dramatically.

Comment: @QZHua: Did you compile Octave yourself? Or did you download binaries from somewhere? You might be missing the FLTK library?

Comment: Also: what OS do you use? I don't know how that affects things, but it might be relevant. I'm on Linux Ubuntu, have Octave 4.4.1, the default toolkit seems to be "qt", but also have "fltk" and "gnuplot". The gnuplot output is by far the prettiest, IMO. I don't see what you see when I use that toolkit.